# Autocomplete problem in TeXStudio 2.3

Tags: bibliographies, editors, texstudio

I am having problem in autocomplete feature of TeXStudio 2.3 under Windows 7 x64. Most of the times, I don't have the autocomplete of all the commands of the loaded packages as well as the bibliography items, and etc. Especially, for the bibliography, I have to check the bibliography file and look it up there. Fortunately, autocomplete issue fixes by itself randomly and I don't know how I should correct them at the times when it does not work. I tried the tips given in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106607/23594) but no success.

Here is the TeXStudio configuration window for autocomplete. It does not have any bibliography entry.

[image]

I am using it with `classicthesis`. I would be grateful if someone could shed light on this problem.

Answer (score 4):

First, I would recommended updating TexStudio to 2.5.2 version. Go to options -> Configure TexStudio -> Completion, tick all packages you need to have auto-completion of their commands -> Ok, in the example below, `biblatex` package, and autocomplete is shown for the `\parencite{}` corresponding command. Alternatively, you may try also direct copy & paste approach from your citation manager software (if you use one), I use Zotero and I find this approach much easier to copy the citation key directly from Zotero of the selected reference(s) and paste it directly into the TexStudio, [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18848/workflow-for-managing-references/114973#114973) link would explain how.
To install packages for win7 64bit you can install from [here](http://miktex.org/download) the 64-bit net installer and then install all packages from within the package manager (Admin), it will take time to install all other packages or you select what you need, I do always all packages though.
After installation, MikTex should ship with `bibtex` and `biblatex` packages, you should be able to show the current MikTex version from TexStudio if you go to Help -> Check LaTeX installation.
[image]
[image]
 [image]

[image]

Comment: I am using the editor that comes with MiKTeX. It does not have `biblatex.cwl`. How should I know if I should use `biblatex.cwl` or `bibtex.cwl`? How can I add them?

Comment: @Ahm TeXStudio isn't, AFAIK, included in MikTeX. Can't you just [download](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/#download) and install the newest version? If you use `biblatex`, then you should use `biblatex.cwl` I suppose.

Comment: I installed version 2.5.2 but still autocomplete does not work for bibliography. Can it be because of `classicthesis` package?

Comment: @Ahm, pls make sure you install the latest MikTeX version that should ship with `biblatex` package. I use win7 32bit, and 64bit at work, in the TexStudio, you should be able to show that package if installed and in TexStudio if you go to Help -> check LaTeX installation you should be able to see the MikTex version installed also. BTW, autocomplete feature can only work if you tell TexStudio where your `.bib` file is, in `biblatex` this can be done by `\add\addbibresource{C:/Users/<yourpath>/<yourfilename>.bib}` in preamble. It seems to be an issue of pkg installation rather than conflict

Comment: @Ahm, see my updated answer of how to install the packages on win7, 64 platform, I hope this would be helpful.

Comment: If I update it, will I get into trouble? I am afraid of other things that are dependent on the previous version. Please advise.

Comment: @Ahm, if your deadline is very near, then better to stay on your version, if not better to update. I did this update and found some pkgs were obsolete, some were removed, some are replaced by better ones, but that should be easy to identify then. Alternatively, you can install manually the pkg you need without the need to install all, but this can be sometimes problematic if the new pkg is dependent on pkges you don't have, then you should install them manually too.

Comment: @doctorate: Thanks. I updated everything according to your instruction. I get the following error when I add `\add\addbibresource{mybibliography.bib}` in the preamble: `Undefined control sequence \add` and `Undefined control sequence \add\addbibresource`. Could you help me fix this error?

Comment: I am using `classicthesis` package and my `Bibliography.tex` is located in the folder named `FrontBackMatter`. When I have `\bibliography{../Bibliography}` in the file `Bibliography.tex`, I am able to see the entries in the bibliography. However, it does not succeed in putting the citation in the document itself by using for example `\citep{}`. When I change it back to `\bibliography{Bibliography}`, the citation works perfectly in the document but autocomplete fails to show me the entries.

Comment: I have created a new question which is posted here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116164/23594 just to prevent confusion for other users. Thanks.