# Problem in bibliography autocompletion in TeXStudio 2.5.2

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, texstudio

This question is the continuation of my previous question in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116071/23594). I have updated everything according to the instructions given there in the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116076/23594) of @doctorate.

The problem that I have is the autocpmplete list in TeXStudio 2.5.2 for bibliography entries. Unfortunately, updating did not fix the autocomplete issue. I am using `classicthesis` package and my Bibliography.tex is located in the folder named `FrontBackMatter`. I came up with a solution for autocomplete by having:

```
\bibliography{../Bibliography}
```

in the file `Bibliography.tex`. This will allow me to see the entries of the bibliography in autocomplete list (very cool). However, the problem is that the compiler does not succeed in putting the citations in the document itself by using for example `\citep{}`. When I change it back to:

```
\bibliography{Bibliography}
```

in the file `Bibliography.tex`, the citation works perfectly in the document but autocomplete fails to show me the entries.

I should say that my problem is not `\citep{keylist}`. `\citep{keylist}` is shown in the autocomplete because `natbin.cwl` is already selected. Actually, I would like to see `\citep{bibitem1}`, `\citep{bibitem2}`, ..., `\citep{bibitemN}` in the autocomplete list so that I can easily select the bibliography entries by scrolling through them. Unfortunately, the autocomplete list in my `TeXStudio` only shows the commands.

Could someone help me find the solution to issue?

Comment: I've always thought that the subdivision of the input files proposed by André Miede is faulty. Just put `Bibliography.bib` in the same directory as the main file. The `.bib` file *doesn't* belong to the front or back matter. It's something different that isn't even related to the document you're writing, as it's a database reusable for as many document as you want.

Comment: @egreg: `Bibliography.bib` is in the same folder as `main.tex`. But `Bibliography.tex` is in another folder named `FrontBackMatter`. To examine your commend, I put them in the same folder as `main.tex` but it did not solve the problem of autocompleting the bibliography entries.

Comment: Why do you even have a `Bibliography.tex`? Is there much more in it than the bibliography command?

Comment: @Juri Robl: Thanks. That solved my problem. I put the content of `Bibloiography.tex` inside `main.tex` and autocomplete now shows all the entries in `Bibliography.bib`.

Comment: @Ahm In my opinion there's no point in having a two line `Bibliography.tex` file. Move the code in the main file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it isn't an issue related to LaTeX. It's an editor issue and so you should contact the author of TeXStudio. This can be done at sourceforge:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/texstudio/

Comment: thanks. I have posted the issue, which can be found here: http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907839/thread/9aaff015/#9e2a

Comment: @A2009 it's a shame no one ever replied. Did you find a solution? If not, I'll report it as a bug. I already have my bibliography commands in my main.tex, but I have the problem you described above.

Comment: @Laua: I did not find any solution and I stopped using this feature.

Comment: @A2009 I solved the issue for myself and posted a reply at sourceforge. Hope it works for you too! https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907839/thread/9aaff015/