# texstudio autocompletion bibliography

Tags: texstudio

Normally Texstudio auto-proposes references that are defined within the biblatex file when I type `\cite`.

Instead it just shows `\cite{keylist}`.

I already checked `Options->Configure->Completion`, but without success.

Comment: In my case, all commands like usepackage were in an included file.
Putting \addbibresource in the main.tex file solved it.

Answer (score 1):

`texstudio` looks for the bib file(s) in the folder same as `main.tex`. If it is not available there, it also looks for a path which can be set in the (see image too)

```
 Preferences -->  Adv. Editor --> Additional Search Paths --> Bib Files:
```

[image]

This is useful if you have one (or more) central bib directory which could be used in several documents.

And then as you said, it should work without any problem --

[image]

Comment: thx amit for your answer. I tried this, but it didn't do the trick. my problem was, that `addbibresource`  was wrapped in a custom command. After unwrapping everything worked for me. other users my have a look at this answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262629/107887

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the file names starting with capital or small letters are referred in \include in the same way.

For example if your file is called Example.tex and you type \include{example.tex} in your main.tex file the autocomplete some times does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In case auto-completion is activated and you provided the correct search path, you might have a look whether you correctly included `addbibresource` to your latex code:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262629/107887

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when configuring Textstudio's "Additional Search Paths" under the "Adv. Editor" tab, one must specify the exact folder that contains the bib file (rather than any of its parent folders) in order for auto-completion of bib entries to work properly with only `\bibliography{bibfile}`. Alternatively, one can indicate the absolute path to the bib file in the manner of `\bibliography{C:/path/to/bibfile}`. In addition, in order to have MikTex know where to look for personal bib-related files such as .csf and .bst files, one also needs to open the MikTex Console's settings with admin privilege to add a personal TEXMF directory (can be named as "localtexmf" for example) containing the bib and other files according to the appropriate file structure. After this, also click the "Tasks" tab at the top and select "Refresh file name database". This way, all related files in your personal TEXMF directory can be accessed by MikTex when compiling.